# Why XnViewMP not working in 16.10?

Tags: software-installation, 16.10

I installed XnViewMP deb package by using GDebi, as have done it dozens of times before in previous Ubuntu versions. The installation finishes successfully, yet XnViewMP won't start, not even after full reboot. Already uninstalled/reinstalled it twice. No success. Anything else i should do to make it work?

Comment: Is there an error if you try to run it from the command line?

Comment: I tried `sudo xnviewmp`. Nothing. No response from the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's discussion on official forums: http://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=33933 XNviewMP is not working because of missing gstreamer0.10 packages. Proceed with caution if you'll try installing packages from another Ubuntu version.

On a side note, to run xnview from command line use `xnview` command, not `xnviewmp`.

Comment: `sudo xnview` gives this response: /opt/XnView/XnView: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory .

Answer (score 0):

I did this first: Got this command from:  https://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?t=32986

Code: Select all

apt install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0

Then installed all 16.10 updates. Still would not launch. Clicked on Ubuntu  settings icon, top right on desktop, then 'About tjis Computer' then 'Defeult Applications'. In the drop down menu under 'Photos' XnViewMP was listed and I selected it as default app. Opened a photo snd it opened with XnViewMP, thrn I locked it (XnViewMP} to the launcher. Now it works fine. I'm pretty much a novice but I researched and got lucky by looking  at the 'Default Apps' while ipdating Ubuntu.